# Toggle Show/Hide on StackExchange

Tags: discussion

There are some posts which give solutions for Latex, but no one seems to work here on StackExchange. Is it possible to use this toggle show/hide here on StackExchange? Like when I want to toggle show/hide a mathematical proof.

Here is an example (though math doesn't seem to work here...).

Theorem: $$n>n-1 \forall n\in{\mathbb{N}}$$

proof:
\toggle_on show/hide
For $n=1$ the statement $1>0$ is obviously true. Suppose it is true for $n$ then for $n\rightarrow n+1$ it follows $$n+1>n-1+1=n \quad \square \, .$$
\toggle_off \show/hide

**edit:** LoL? Are you guys serious? Read my question again... This is not about math displaying using MathJax. It was just used as an example, because somebody asked for it and then I realized math doesn't even work here. But I don't actually care! The question is about a toggle option you also sometimes find on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem#Form_for_a_material_element

Comment: This belongs on Meta. Voted to migrate.

Comment: Are you talking about a "spoiler"?

Comment: Sort of yes....

Comment: Perhaps you want OCGs (optional content groups, aka PDF Layers)? Pkg [`ocgx2`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx2) could help you.

Comment: How can I bind packages here on StackExchange?

Comment: So is it possible?

Comment: @Diger: If by packages you mean (La)TeX packages, then you can't. You can only post markdown-related content.

Comment: markdown-related content?

Comment: Can you make an example if that is close to what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you edit the question and explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve? I don't quite get what you want.

Comment: There you go...

Comment: Can you clarify if this is about formatting posts on tex.stackexchange.com or about creating a pdf?

Comment: I want to do this on math.stackexchange.com and was wondering if it is possible there...

Comment: No, it is not possible here. We want and need to see the LaTeX code at all times.

Comment: I guess the confusion is partly fuelled by the fact that this question was first asked on the main site (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488679/35864), which is only about LaTeX and not about markdown or StackExchange, and also by the fact that LaTeX and mathematical proofs are mentioned so prominently. Last but not least, there is not a lot this per-site meta can do about general markdown rendering, most of that is network-wide and then https://meta.stackexchange.com/ would be the right place to discuss this.

Comment: Even more confusingly, you mention that you want to do this on https://math.stackexchange.com/, but you ask here (on TeX.SX).

Comment: Maybe the confusion arose on my part, because when MathJax worked on math.stackexchange I assumed it would work anywhere. I then figured that this toggle option could be implemented in LaTeX and so it might be possible to "compile" a toggle option inside the MathJax environment as part of LaTeX. That's why I went to tex.stackexchange; I never thought about asking this on Tex/Meta. Now I see that if that option would be implemented at all, it would probably make sense to become a network wide feature. But I would be interested if such an option is still possible to be "compiled" inside MathJax.

Comment: Note that MathJax is decidedly not (La)TeX (it only borrows the syntax) and that MathJax questions are in general off-topic on TeX.SX.

Answer (score 4):

The closest we have to show/hide is the "spoiler" blockquote. But it always occupies the space it would occupy if the content were shown, so you don't win a lot if you want to save space.

See [Add markdown support for hidden-until-you-click text (aka spoilers)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1191) and [What's the exact syntax for spoiler markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72877).

```
>! This is a spoiler
```

becomes

> ! This is a spoiler

The feature request for collapsible content has been declined: [Please add the ability to fold blocks of code in questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5199)

In any case, such requests should probably be brought forward network-wide on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ and not on this per-site meta.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the folding I wanted to use was to save space. In that sense it is not an option. And I can not actually believe that this feature was already considered 6 years ago, but rejected...

Comment: So i see that this toggling option can be implemented by JavaScript. But JS only works on META and not even here on Tex/Meta, why?

Comment: @Diger I don't know what exactly you mean with JavaScript works on meta, but not here, but I doubt I could answer the *why* even if I knew what you mean. Sometimes SE move in mysterious ways.

Comment: I meant: 
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

alert('Most folded code ever!');

<!-- end snippet -->

which you find on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers when you scroll down to SeldomNeedys answer.